# Top K Frequent Words

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given an array of strings words and an integer k, return the k most frequent strings.
Return the answer sorted by the frequency from highest to lowest. Sort the words with the same frequency by their lexicographical order.

**Example 1:**

Input: words = ["i","love","leetcode","i","love","coding"], k = 2
Output: ["i","love"]
Explanation: "i" and "love" are the two most frequent words.
Note that "i" comes before "love" due to a lower alphabetical order.

i'm trying to solve this problem using Frequencies and store the most ones and loop k times to get all of them but i have a problem i can't return them as a lexicographical order
upd : i solved it thanks !

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> topKFrequent(vector<string>& words, int k) {
         int n =words.size();
        map<string ,int > Freq;
      
        for (int i = 0 ; i< n;i++)
            Freq[words[i]]++;
        
        vector<pair<string ,int >>result;
        vector<string>ans;
        for (auto it : Freq)
            result.push_back({it.first,it.second});
        sort(result.begin(),result.end());
        for (int i = 0 ; i < min(k,n);i++)
            ans.push_back(result[i].first);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't forget about `for (auto &&word : words)` You're doing something similar later, so it's odd to see a mix of clunky and elegant.

Comment: Tip: Inspect your intermediate structures.

Comment: There's a popular myth about a secret shortcut to becoming an elite C++ guru: throw away your C++ textbooks; instead do random coding puzzles that, otherwise, have no inherent learning value, they don't teach anything except bad programming habits. This myth comes from many clickbait web sites, like LeetCode, that promise that doing their puzzles turns anyone into an instant C++ uberhacker. Everyone eventually realizes how useless these coding puzzles are, but only after wasting a massive amount of time doing one coding puzzle after another. And they have nothing to show for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use compare function as a third parameter in the sort function.
compare function will sort the values as you want exactly!

```
class Solution {
public:
static bool cmp(pair<string ,int > &p1 ,  pair<string ,int > &p2)
    {
        if (p1.second == p2.second)return p1.first < p2.first ;
            return p1.second > p2.second;
    } 
    vector<string> topKFrequent(vector<string>& words, int k) {
         int n =words.size();
        map<string ,int > Freq;

        for (int i = 0 ; i< n;i++)
            Freq[words[i]]++;

        vector<pair<string ,int >>result;
        vector<string>ans;
        for (auto &it : Freq)
            result.push_back({it.first,it.second});
        sort(result.begin(),result.end(),cmp);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < min(k,n);i++)
            ans.push_back(result[i].first);
        return ans;
    }
};
```